# Cannot compile FSM sample code

Tags: c++, state-machine

There is a nice state machine tutorial called [UML Tutorial: Finite State Machines](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlfsm.pdf) by Robert C. Martin. But I can't compile the sample code it provides. I got *FsmTest.cpp(46) : error C2664: 'SetState' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class UnlockedState *' to 'class TurnstileState *'*

Please, help. Thanks.

```
class Turnstile
{
public:
    virtual void Lock();
    virtual void Unlock();
    virtual void Thankyou();
    virtual void Alarm();
};

class TurnstileFSM;
class LockedState;
class UnlockedState;

class TurnstileState
{
public:
    virtual void Coin(TurnstileFSM*) = 0;
    virtual void Pass(TurnstileFSM*) = 0;
protected:
    static LockedState lockedState;
    static UnlockedState unlockedState;
};

class TurnstileFSM : public Turnstile
{
public:
    void SetState(TurnstileState* s) {itsState = s;}
    void Coin() {itsState->Coin(this);}
    void Pass() {itsState->Pass(this);}


private:
    TurnstileState *itsState;
};

class LockedState : public TurnstileState
{
public:
    virtual void Coin(TurnstileFSM* t)
    {
        t->SetState(&unlockedState);
        t->Unlock();
    }
    virtual void Pass(TurnstileFSM* t)
    {
        t->Alarm();
    }
};

class UnlockedState : public TurnstileState
{
public:
    virtual void Coin(TurnstileFSM* t)
    {
        t->Thankyou();
    }
    virtual void Pass(TurnstileFSM* t)
    {
        t->SetState(&lockedState);
        t->Lock();
    }
};

LockedState TurnstileState::lockedState;
UnlockedState TurnstileState::unlockedState;
```

Comment: Oh, "Finite State Machine".  I thought you meant "Flying Spaghetti Monster". :-)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you try to call `SetState()` inside of `LockedState::Coin()`, the class `UnlockedState` is an **incomplete type**: it has been *declared* but not *defined*.  In order to fix it, you'll need to move the definition of of `Coin()` to after that of `UnlockedState`:

```
class LockedState : public TurnstileState
{
public:
    virtual void Coin(TurnstileFSM* t);
    ...
};

class UnlockedState : public TurnstileState
{
    ...
};

void LockedState::Coin(TurnstileFSM* t)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because it does not know UnlockedState is a subclass of TurnstileState yet. Remove the function from inside the class to the end of the file:

```
class TurnstileFSM {
    void SetState(TurnstileState* s);
};

void TurnstileFSM::SetState(TurnstileState* s) {itsState = s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the generated code should include the *tscontext.h*, and the *TurnStyle* class is derived from the context, which should be declared in *tscontext.h" as *class TurnStyleContext*.

In my case the generated code looks like this:

```
    #include "tscontext.h"   // the header file name for the context class"

    // Forward Declarations

    class TurnStyle;

    //----------------------------------------------
    // TurnStyleState: The base state class
    //----------------------------------------------
    class TurnStyleState
    {
      public: 
        virtual const char* StateName() const = 0;
        virtual void Coin( TurnStyle& );
        virtual void Pass( TurnStyle& );
    };

    //----------------------------------------------
    // State: Unlocked
    //----------------------------------------------
    class TurnStyleUnlockedState : public TurnStyleState
    {
      public: 
        virtual const char* StateName() const
            { return "Unlocked"; }
        virtual void Pass( TurnStyle& );
        virtual void Coin( TurnStyle& );
    };
    //----------------------------------------------
    // State: Locked
    //----------------------------------------------
    class TurnStyleLockedState : public TurnStyleState
    {
      public: 
        virtual const char* StateName() const
            { return "Locked"; }
        virtual void Coin( TurnStyle& );
        virtual void Pass( TurnStyle& );
    };
    //----------------------------------------------
    // TurnStyle: The Finite State Machine class
    //----------------------------------------------
    class TurnStyle: public TurnStyleContext
    {
      public: 
        // Static State variables
        static TurnStyleUnlockedState Unlocked;
        static TurnStyleLockedState Locked;

        TurnStyle(); // default Constructor

        // Event functions
        virtual void Coin() { itsState->Coin( *this ); }
        virtual void Pass() { itsState->Pass( *this ); }

        // State Accessor functions
        void SetState( TurnStyleState& theState ) { itsState = &theState; }
        TurnStyleState& GetState() const { return *itsState; }

        const char* GetCurrentStateName() const { return itsState->StateName(); }
        const char* GetVersion() const;

      private: 
        TurnStyleState* itsState;
    };
```

with the state machine defined this way:

```
Context TurnStyleContext     // the name of the context class
FSMName TurnStyle            // the name of the FSM to create
Initial Locked               // the name of the initial state
                             // for C++ output
pragma Header  tscontext.h"   // the header file name for the context class, note the necessary "
{
    Locked
    {
        Coin     Unlocked    Unlock
        Pass     Locked      Alarm
    }
    Unlocked <BeforeUnlocked >AfterUnlocked
    {
        Coin    Unlocked    Thankyou
        Pass    Locked      Lock
    }
}
```

The context implements *FSMError, Thankyou, Lock, Alarm, Unlock, BeforeUnlocked, AfterUnlocked*